# Substitute a variable's value in PySpark lambda function

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How should I be able to use a variable inside a lambda function ?

```
for a_name in name_field_names:
    results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM noise_data")
    stringsDS = results.map(lambda p:p.(a_name))
```

The lambda function is expecting me to give the name of the column, whereas I am giving a variable.

How should I pass the value of the a_name variable to the lambda function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a variable from `Row` by name use bracket notation:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row(a = "foo", b = "bar")
row["a"]
```

```
'foo'
```

or `getattr`:

```
getattr(row, "b")
```

```
'bar'
```

You can also skip `map` and use `select`:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM noise_data").select(a_name)
```

Also remember that Python late bindings. Using variable from the closure inside a function called in a loop is not a good idea. If you want `map` you should rather capture `a_name` as an attribute, for example:

```
from operator import attrgetter

for a_name in name_field_names:
    results = ...
    results.rdd.map(attrgetter(a_name)))
```